# Quicksort on 5000 element array

Tags: java

Good morning folks,
  I wanted to get some clarity on the big O notation for a quicksort on an array of 5000 elements.  I am running the quicksort in random order (200, 20, 4 etc...), sorted order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc...) and reverse sorted order (4999, 4998, 4997, 4996 etc....) and I am selecting the pivot from the middle.

When I look up the Big O notation that tells me that for a quicksort it is O (n log n) which means to me.... when using base 2 log, O(5000 * 12.287712) = 61438.56, and if using base 10 log O(5000 * 3.69897) = 18494.85 so I am assuming I would use the 61438.56 and when I look at my output (posted below) it does not take nearly that long.

I am just trying to get an idea when doing comparison as to what I would generally expect to see from a random order, sorted order, and reverse sorted order test.  I have posted results of 5 runs through my java code and maybe I am over thinking it or doing the comparison in the wrong place but I guess I would have though there would have been a larger difference in comparisons on the different passes.

I can post my code if necessary, just had problems as I could not get it to indent 4 spaces and not sure if there is an automated way to do it.

1st run:
Random-Order-Number of swaps made 16196
Sorted-Order-Number of swaps made 18242
Reverse-Sorted-Number of swaps made 22790

2nd Run:
Random-Order-Number of swaps made 16072
Sorted-Order-Number of swaps made 18118
Reverse-Sorted-Number of swaps made 22666

3rd Run:
Random-Order-Number of swaps made 16205
Sorted-Order-Number of swaps made 18251
Reverse-Sorted-Number of swaps made 22799

4th Run:
Random-Order-Number of swaps made 16333
Sorted-Order-Number of swaps made 18379
Reverse-Sorted-Number of swaps made 22927

5th Run:
Random-Order-Number of swaps made 16283
Sorted-Order-Number of swaps made 18329
Reverse-Sorted-Number of swaps made 22877

```
    package QuickSort;

import java.util.Random;


public class QuickSortApp
{

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      // This for loop just runs through the code 20 times.
      for(int loop = 0; loop < 20; loop++)
      {

    // This creates an array with 5000 random numbers    
    int maxSize = 5000;
    ArrayQuickSort arr;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    arr = new ArrayQuickSort(maxSize);
    ArrayQuickSort.setSwapCount(0);
    ArrayQuickSort.setMedianCount(0);
    for (int j = 0; j < maxSize; j++)
    {
      int n = rnd.nextInt(50000);
      arr.insert(n);
    }

    // This creates a sorted array to test
    ArrayQuickSort arrSorted;
    arrSorted = new ArrayQuickSort(maxSize);
    ArrayQuickSort.setSwapCount(0);
    ArrayQuickSort.setMedianCount(0);
    for (int j = 0; j < maxSize; j++)
    {
      int n = j + 1;
      arrSorted.insert(n);
    }

    // This creates a reverse sorted array for checks
    ArrayQuickSort arrReverseSorted;
    arrReverseSorted = new ArrayQuickSort(maxSize);
    ArrayQuickSort.setSwapCount(0);
    ArrayQuickSort.setMedianCount(0);
    for (int j = 5000; j > 0; j--)
    {
      int n = j;
      arrReverseSorted.insert(n);
    }

    arr.quickSort();
    System.out.println("Random-Order-Number of swaps made " + ArrayQuickSort.getSwapCount() + " Recursion Count is " + ArrayQuickSort.getMedianCount() );
    arrSorted.quickSort();
    System.out.println("Sorted-Order-Number of swaps made " + ArrayQuickSort.getSwapCount() + " Recursion Count is " + ArrayQuickSort.getMedianCount());
    arrReverseSorted.quickSort();
    System.out.println("Reverse-Sorted-Number of swaps made " + ArrayQuickSort.getSwapCount() + " Recursion Count is " + ArrayQuickSort.getMedianCount());

    }  
  }
}


    package QuickSort;

public class ArrayQuickSort {

    private int[] theArray;
    private int nElms;
    private static int swapCount=0;
    private static int medianCount = 0;


    public ArrayQuickSort(int max) {
        theArray = new int[max];
        nElms = 0;
    }

    public void insert(int value) {
        theArray[nElms] = value;
        nElms++;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.print("Array = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nElms; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(theArray[i] + " ");
            if(i%25==0)
                System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void swap(int dx1, int dx2) {
        int temp = theArray[dx1];
        theArray[dx1] = theArray[dx2];
        theArray[dx2] = temp;
        swapCount++;  // I am counting here to see how many times numbers are swapped.
    }

    private int medianOf3(int left, int right)
    {
        int center =(left+right)/2;

        if(theArray[left] > theArray[center])
            swap(left, center);
        if(theArray[left] > theArray[right])
            swap(left, right);
        if(theArray[center] > theArray[right])
            swap(center, right);

        swap(center, right);
        medianCount++;   // I am counting here to see how many times the pivot is changed
        return theArray[right];

    }

    public void quickSort()
    {
        recQuickSort(0, nElms -1);
    }

    private void recQuickSort(int left, int right)
    {
        int size = right-left+1;
        if(size < 5)
            insertionSort(left, right);
        else
        {
            int median = medianOf3(left, right);
            int partition = partitionIt(left, right, median);
            recQuickSort(left, partition-1);
            recQuickSort(partition+1, right);

        }
    }

    private int partitionIt(int left, int right, int pivot) {
        int leftPtr = left - 1;
        int rightPtr = right;

        while (true) {
            while (theArray[++leftPtr] < pivot)
            ;
            while (theArray[--rightPtr] > pivot)
            ;
            if(leftPtr >= rightPtr)
                break;
            else
                swap(leftPtr, rightPtr);
        }
        swap(leftPtr, right);
        return leftPtr;
    }



    private void insertionSort(int left, int right) {
        int in, out;

        for (out = left + 1; out <= right; out++) {
            int temp = theArray[out];
            in = out;
            while (in > left && theArray[in - 1] >= temp) {
                theArray[in] = theArray[in - 1];
                in--;
            }
            theArray[in] = temp;
        }
    }

     public static int getMedianCount()
  {
    return medianCount;
  }

  public static void setMedianCount(int medianCount)
  {
    ArrayQuickSort.medianCount = medianCount;
  }

  public static int getSwapCount()
  {
    return swapCount;
  }

  public static void setSwapCount(int swapCount)
  {
    ArrayQuickSort.swapCount = swapCount;
  }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I think you need to read up on the Big O concept http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. The key phrase is: "A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function."

Comment: I guess my question is, do the results I am seeing appear to be about right?  Does it seem correct that the different arrays would have such similar results?  Since I am not a math guy and only have a topical understanding of big-O notation, I came to ask experts who better understand it.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to realize that big-Oh is used to describe the *asymptotic behaviour* of an algorithm, that is *the rate of growth*. It is also an *upper bound*, which may or may not be tight.

Due to these factors, you can't compute how many operations the algorithm will require just by knowing its big-Oh time complexity.

> When I look up the Big O notation that tells me that for a quicksort it is O (n log n)

It is in the average case. However, it is likely that in the worst case, your implementation is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I just thought it odd that the random array, sorted array, and reverse sorted arrays had similar counts so was verifying if that is probable expected behavior.  I am using a middle pivot point.

Comment: @wfsteadman: I agree that it is odd. It is impossible to say more without seeing your code.

Comment: So I wanted to put my code in, but is there a method to add it without having to indivdually indent each line of code?  Would love to add it here... goes off to find out how to add the code.

Answer (score -1):

I think the O-Notation gives you the number of comparisions you have to make during sorting and not the actual swaps. If you count the number of comparisons you should get numbers around  the expected value, as an average.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to change where I am counting from.  I guess I am still confused on what a normal/average result would be for an array of 5000 elements.  If I better understood that, I would then be able to know where my counters belonged.